# django heroku whitenoise issute( static files loading related)

Tags: django, heroku, deployment

By **heroku logs --tail**, I got these errors:

> ImportError:
>    Your WhiteNoise configuration is incompatible with WhiteNoise v4.0

and

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: WSGI application
>   'myproject.wsgi.application' could not be loaded; Error importing
>   module.

in my wsgi.py(I intentionly removed whitenoise-related lines):

```
import os
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
from dj_static import Cling
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'notetaking.settings')
application = Cling(get_wsgi_application())
```

in Procfile:

```
worker: gunicorn --pythonpath notetaking notetaking.wsgi
```

in prod_settings.py

```
from .settings import *
STATIC_ROOT='staticfiles'
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO','https')
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
DEBUG = False
import dj_database_url
DATABASES = {
    'default': dj_database_url.config()
}
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.django.GzipManifestStaticFilesStorage'
```

in requirements.py

```
dj-database-url==0.5.0
dj-static==0.0.6
Django==2.1.5
djangorestframework==3.9.1
gunicorn==19.9.0
mysqlclient==1.3.13
numpy==1.16.0
pandas==0.23.4
Pillow==5.4.1
psycopg2==2.7.7
python-dateutil==2.7.5
pytz==2018.9
six==1.12.0
static3==0.7.0
virtualenv==16.2.0
whitenoise==4.0
xlrd==1.2.0
```

Comment: I don't know why but with debug = true, the website runs finely.

Comment: You don't need both Cling and Whitenoise, they do the same job. If you're adding Whitenoise, remove Cling.